# Facebook C# SDK ASP.Net 3.5 Examples

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been asked to develop a facebook application that allows users of their current system to find each other using a this facebook app. Unfortuantely their requirements are that it has to be build in ASP.NET 3.5 (Easier for their clients distribution purposes).

I am a experienced PHP developer although I have in the past used C# for windows applications. I have found a facebook api that looks suitable - http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/. The problem I am having is that all availble examples use .NET 4.

I must admit I'm struggling to get to grips with the api and I know from the past I learn best through example. Could anyone provide a link to examples or some basic code I experiment with?

I would really appreciate any advice or input you have on the situation. 
Thanks, Jason.

**Update**

Using the answer below and the following resource (http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/) it is easy enough to make start on facebook application.

One issue I also had was the server (1&1) I was using needed proxy setting added to the web.config

Example:

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy>
       <proxy
          usesystemdefault = "false"
          bypassonlocal="false"
          proxyaddress="http://ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net:3128"
       />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until you become more familiar with ASP.NET, I would suggest integrating with the FacebookClient() rather than the more involved

the one thing you will have to understand is the difference between `dynamic` and using `IDictionary`.  For C# 4.0 and up you can use `dynamic`, but for 3.5 you must use the old `IDictionary`.

Here's a good example of how to convert from dynamic to IDictionary (so you can use the 4.0 examples as a guide)

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("{access_token}");

dynamic result = fb.Get("/me");
var name = result.name;

Response.Write("Hi " + name);
```

Converts to:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("{access_token}");

var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me");
var name = (string)result["name"];

Response.Write("Hi " + name);
```

I hope that gets you on your way as far as converting the examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its been helpful. I've added a little to my question if you have the time to look at it that would be brilliant, cheers.

Comment: You will want to get the user access token.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for starters.  What I do is use the FB.login() function of the Javascript SDK and when I get the token, I AJAX it up to my server to use.  If you'd prefer to use the more streamlined methods of the C# SDK, then you will need to use the non-desktop FacebookClient examples and try to get it hooked into ASP.Net

Comment: Whoo hoo!  Glad to be of assistance.